# Unable to find error in my script doesn't behave as intended

Tags: bash, docker

```
docker run --rm \
/bin/bash -c "\
su - hello && \
echo \"Pre\" && \
python ${M} ${F} ${D} ${B} && \
echo \"Post\" && \
CHECK_VALUE=`$(cat B)` && \
echo ${CHECK_VALUE} && \
"
```

My problem is ${B} is a file produced by python code.
But whenever I run this I get the following log:

```
cat: /home/hello/D/W/H/b.txt: No such file or directory
Pre
Post
```

And also in empty line
This clearly means my python code is unfinished and the next line is run.
Please help How do I read the file into a variable only after its written?
And why such ambiguous behaviour?

Comment: Are you sure this file exists and has name like you expect? Check the extension of that file.

Comment: I use the same variable for file creation and reading

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have multiple errors in this part:

```
`$(cat B)`
```

You are mixing *two* command substitutions.  `$(cat B)` is synonymous to `` `cat B` `` so what you have here is actually equivalent to `$($(cat B))`.  In other words, take the contents of B and use it as a command, then substitute *that* command's output.

Moreover, because you are using double quotes around the command, this construct is evaluated when the command is parsed, not when it is executed.  You can prevent this by backslash-escaping the dollar sign.

Additionally, you need to escape `${CHECK_VALUE}` in order to prevent the shell from interpolating it when evaluating the string, just like the command substitution.  I would also recommend quoting the value, unless you expect it to contain a single token (and perhaps even then, just for your own sanity).

Finally, you have a dangling `&&` with nothing after it.  This is a syntax error.

Here is your script with my fixes:

```
docker run --rm \
/bin/bash -c "\
    su - hello && \
    echo \"Pre\" && \
    python ${M} ${F} ${D} ${B} && \
    echo \"Post\" && \
    CHECK_VALUE=\"\$(cat B)\" && \
    echo \"\${CHECK_VALUE}\""
```

I also added quotes around the `cat` in case its output contains shell metacharacters.

... though capturing a variable just so you can `echo` it is an [antipattern](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#echo); probably you simply want to `cat ${B}` as the final command.

If you expect `su - hello` to cause the *subsequent*  commands to run as `hello`, that's also wrong (though a common newbie mistake).  `su` spawns a new shell and the following command will execute when that shell is *terminated* (not inside it).  You probably mean `su -c "python $M $F $D $B" hello && cat "$B"` plain and simple.  Wrapping it in the `docker` command line, try

```
docker run --rm \
/bin/bash -c "su -c 'python $M $F $D $B' hello && cat $B"
```

where the single quotes do not prevent variable interpolation, because inside the double quotes, they are not actually quoting anything (compare `echo "don't"` where obviously the apostrophe would be problematic if in fact it had quoting semantics).

Comment: The formatting errors in your comment make it hard to see what you need help with.  You get `code` formatting by using backticks (ASCII 96) around the code snippet.

Comment: `CHECK_VALUE=\"\$(cat $B)\" && \ ` is how it works.
event though cat: /home/hello/D/W/H/b.txt: No such file or directory is gone
But still the value in `${CHECK_VALUE}` is empty `please help!`

Comment: Then the problem is with your English, not with your formatting.  I don't understand what you mean.  Did you review my latest edits to this answer?

Comment: It maybe an antipattern but how else do you check that a variable contains value or not? I need the values in the file on the latter parts of my script The point is it still doesn't work.

Comment: If `cat "$B"` returns no output, then your Python script failed to populate the file named by the variable `B`.

Comment: I can see that file for data. I am running it on my local system. 
`CHECK_VALUE=\"\$(cat $BUILD_FILE)\" && \
  echo ${CHECK_VALUE} && \ `
This doesn't work
But I do see the file data if I just use:
`CHECK_VALUE=\"\$(cat $BUILD_FILE)\" && \
  echo ${CHECK_VALUE} && \ `
So the problem now seems to be I can't read file to variable

Comment: Neither of these should work with the trailing `&&` -- like I stated in my answer, that's a syntax error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97279/discussion-between-tripleee-and-user1615664).